# Can we use DocumentDB with Ruby on Rails + Node.js

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, azure-cosmosdb

I knew we can use node.js in Ruby on Rails, now my requirement is to use DocumentDB Nosql database, I knew microsoft provided SDK for node.js. Please let me know if anyone tried or have any idea whether we can use Ruby on Rails + Node.js for documentDB.

There is REST support for other programming language in DocumentDb but would like to take advantage of their Node.js SDK

Comment: DocumentDB is a database service, and there's no specific inclusion/exclusion of access for given languages - there's either an SDK or there's direct REST calls. Not sure exactly what your question is (and also why you wouldn't be able to use the node sdk if you so chose to do so).

Comment: Also: Have you tried searching for `documentdb sdk ruby` on the web? I'd think that would be the best place to start.

Comment: David actually my team expertise in Ruby on rails and deployment will be easier as my team is small and people may have taken more interest if we could do that using their loving technology.  Thank you so much for your answer, will give try to nodejs along with express. I can understand there is no point to use ruby on rails unless there is support for ORM like mongodb (Mongoid and mongomapper).

Answer (score 1):

Other than as a build pipeline for client-side javascript code, I'm not aware of any way to "use node.js in Ruby on Rails" at runtime. If you know of something, please provide a link.

There is no official Ruby SDK for DocumentDB but there is [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/azure-documentdb-sdk/versions/0.2.1) community Gem. Alternatively, as David suggests, you can make calls directly to the DocumentDB REST API using your favorite REST client in Ruby. The node.js SDK is just a fairly thin wrapper of the REST API. You could easily build the equivalent for Ruby especially since you would only need to support the aspects of the DocumentDB API that were necessary for your code.

I can envision a micro-services architecture where you ran your DocumentDB code using the node.js SDK and used interprocess communication to connect to your RoR app, however, my instinct is that your situation does not call for that level of complexity.

All of that said, I'm not sure how you would support RoR's data modeling and migration features. You may have to write your own adapter, which would be a significant effort. You might be better off using Express (node.js based) server-side.

Comment: Thank you Larry. I will give try to Express(node.js), actually was looking for easier deployment option as we already expert in Ruby on rails and several application already deployed using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: There is one framework that influenced by ruby on rails http://compoundjs.com/  , it provides rails like structure and commands to generate resource but we can't use it together.  I did not found any ruby gem so far so i can use documenDB with that may be due to documentDb is newly evolving and may come in future.